# Unwrapping an Optional value error in Swift

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, afnetworking-2

According to the question subject it is very frequent question and lot many answers there on stacks but i am confuse with behaviour of the error assurance cases. I am little new to Swift and i have some codes. In this code some times i getting and error of **Unwrapping an Optional value**

Bellow is the code

```
let operation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)
operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject:AnyObject!) -> Void in
var error:NSError?

//Bellow line gives me an error
let responseDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseObject as! NSData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSDictionary
```

`Error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

**Note:** This line gives me and error only when my internet connectivity is down. When internet is totally disconnect then this error not comes up and it goes to `Error` block of AFNetworking. And when internet is fully working then also i did not get this error as well.

Please suggest some modification or replacement in code.

Comment: Please don't tag swift questions with the objective-c tag, this has nothing to do with objective-c

Comment: Sure, will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `responseDict` might not be valid JSON in this case. Whenever you get an error like this, look carefully at all your forced unwrapped optionals. In this case:

```
let responseDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseObject as! NSData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSDictionary
```

Instead use:

```
if let responseDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseObject as! NSData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
    // Response was valid JSON
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap the `responseObject` which is an optional. Most likely it is nil when the connection is down (which makes perfect sense).

```
if let response = responseObject as? NSData {
    let responseDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, ...
}
```